# How to display in html the student name not the foreignkey?

Tags: django, django-templates

Good day everyone, I hope the title is enough for you guys to understand what my problem is, i have this code in my views.py

```
def corevalues(request):
    coregradelevel = request.GET.get('coregradelevel')

    teacher = request.GET.get('teacher')
    corevalues = CoreValues.objects.all().order_by('Display_Sequence')
    corevaluesdescription = CoreValuesDescription.objects.values('Description').distinct('Description').order_by('Description')
    corevaluesperiod = CoreValuesDescription.objects.all().order_by('Display_Sequence')
    print(corevaluesperiod)
    gradelevel = EducationLevel.objects.filter(id__in = coregradelevel).distinct().order_by('id')

    studentcorevalues = StudentsCoreValuesDescription.objects.filter(Teacher = teacher).filter(GradeLevel__in = gradelevel.values_list('id'))\
        .values('Students_Enrollment_Records').distinct('Students_Enrollment_Records').order_by('Students_Enrollment_Records')

    student = StudentSubjectGrade.objects.filter(Teacher = teacher).filter(GradeLevel__in = gradelevel.values_list('id'))\
        .values('Students_Enrollment_Records').distinct('Students_Enrollment_Records').order_by('Students_Enrollment_Records')

    return render(request, 'Homepage/behavior.html',{"studentcorevalues":studentcorevalues,"corevalues":corevalues,"corevaluesdescription":corevaluesdescription,\
                                                     "corevaluesperiod":corevaluesperiod,"student":student})
```

from this line

```
student = StudentSubjectGrade.objects.filter(Teacher = teacher).filter(GradeLevel__in = gradelevel.values_list('id'))\
            .values('Students_Enrollment_Records').distinct('Students_Enrollment_Records').order_by('Students_Enrollment_Records')
```

I filter and distinct the name of the student to remove the duplicate data, but when i display it to my html
, the result is

[image]

it display the foriegnkey not the name of the student even my html is

```
{% for student in student %}

<tr>
<td>{{student.Students_Enrollment_Records}}</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

{% endfor %}
```

this is the query result of student when i print it

```
<QuerySet [{'Students_Enrollment_Records': 1}, {'Students_Enrollment_Records': 5}, {'Students_Enrollment_Records': 9}, {'Students_Enrollment_Records': 13}, {'Students_Enrollment
_Records': 17}]>
```

i dont know why it gets the foreignkey, its too confusing.

**UPDATE** when i tried this

```
student = StudentSubjectGrade.objects.filter(Teacher = teacher).filter(GradeLevel__Description = gradelevel.values_list('Description'))\
        .values('Students_Enrollment_Records').distinct('Students_Enrollment_Records').order_by('Students_Enrollment_Records')
```

the error says **ValueError: The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.**

this is my models.py

```
class EducationLevel(models.Model):
    Sequence = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        suser = '{0.Description}'
        return suser.format(self)


class StudentsCoreValuesDescription(models.Model):
    Teacher = models.ForeignKey(EmployeeUser, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                null=True, blank=True)
    Core_Values = models.ForeignKey(CoreValuesDescription, related_name='+',
                                                    on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)

    Students_Enrollment_Records = models.ForeignKey(StudentsEnrolledSubject, related_name='+',
                                                    on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    GradeLevel = models.ForeignKey(EducationLevel, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                   null=True, blank=True)
    Sections = models.ForeignKey(Section, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    grading_Period = models.ForeignKey(gradingPeriod, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                       null=True, blank=True)
    remarks =  models.TextField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        suser = '{0.Core_Values} - {0.Description}'
        return suser.format(self)
```

Comment: instead of values_list('id')), try with the field name you want to display

Comment: where is your model? You can return string from your models directly with `def __str__()` function

Comment: ive post my models sir, please see the update questions

Answer (score 0):

It gets the ID because that is how it is saved in the database. You can get the object by:

```
User.objects.get(pk=id)

**or**

user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=id)
```

where id = the ID in your QS.

Comment: what do you mean by this?